# Adding attribute to C# marshaling script to handle volume control in Unity plugin

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

Making a C++ plugin for Unity...
I have the following attribute in my Unity .cs marshaling script:

```
[Range(0,1)]
public float Volume = 1f;
private float _currentVolume;

//private float _currentVolume = 1f;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        _isRunning = false;

    if(_currentVolume != Volume)
    {
        Project.project_volume_control((int)(Volume * 25));
    }
}
```

Here's the function in my .cpp file:

```
void project_volume_control(int _currentVolume) {
project_set_volume(_currentVolume, &point);
}
```

Not sure if this is enough info, but I cannot control the volume of my plugin with the code as it stands. I am new to C# and Unity... any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Unity platform, but to invoke C++ from C# in general you can make a C interface, build it as a DLL, and use P/Invoke from C# to call it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/aa288468(v=vs.94) . You can _also_ use C++/CLI to build your C++ code into .NET bytecode, but I've never tried that before.

Comment: Nothing in your C# code indicates you are connecting with a C++ plugin. You'd need to add the DllImport attribute above an extern method declaration that reproduces the signature of the C++ methods. Simpler than it sounds as you can see here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html